# If $g:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}^m$ is continuous and $x_0 \in [a,b]$, prove $|\int_a^b g(x)dx| \geq \int^a_b|g(x)|dx-2\int^a_b|g(x)-g(x_0)|dx$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality, definite-integrals, integral-inequality

This is an exercise from Leoni’s book on Sobolev spaces. It seems elementary but the proof is eluding me despite my repeated attempts to use the reverse triangle inequality and the mean value theorem. There might be a trick I haven’t thought of yet.

Comment: what is $|g(x)|$ in $\mathbb{R}^m$ ?

Comment: Hint: Show that for any constant $c$, one has $\int_a^b \lvert g(x) - \frac1{b-a}\int_a^b g(y)\,\mathrm{d} y \rvert \,\mathrm{d}x \leq 2\int_a^b \lvert g(x) - c \rvert \,\mathrm{d}x$.

Comment: Are you saying that this exercise requires the use of BMO?

Comment: @maxematician This inequality does come up there, but it is itself elementary and can be proven using the triangle inequality and Fubini. Can you see how this can be applied to prove the inequality in question?

Comment: @ktoi I think I’m really close. In your proposed inequality, I have LHS $\leq (b-a)^{-1}\int^b_a \int^b_a |g(x)-g(y)|dydx$. But I don’t think we have the bound $|g(x)-g(y)| \leq 2|g(x)-c|$, which would prove your suggested inequality.

Comment: @maxematician You're almost there, I've posted an answer which includes the key estimate you're missing to conclude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea, as suggested in the comments, is to use the inequality:
$$ \int_a^b \left\lvert g(x) - \frac1{b-a} \int_a^b g(y) \,\mathrm{d}y\right\rvert \,\mathrm{d}x \leq 2 \int_a^b \lvert g(x) - c \rvert \,\mathrm{d}x \tag{$\dagger$}$$
for all $c \in \mathbb R^m$. If this holds, we can then apply this with $c = g(x_0)$ to estimate
\begin{align}
  \int_a^b \lvert g(x) \rvert\,\mathrm{d}x &\leq \int_a^b \left\lvert g(x) - \frac1{b-a} \int_a^b g(y) \,\mathrm{d}y\right\rvert \,\mathrm{d}x + \int_a^b\left\lvert\frac1{b-a} \int_a^b g(y) \,\mathrm{d}y\right\rvert\,\mathrm{d}x \\
&\leq 2 \int_a^b \lvert g(x) - g(x_0)\rvert \,\mathrm{d}x  + \left\lvert \int_a^b g(y) \,\mathrm{d}y\right\rvert,
\end{align}
which we can rearrange to arrive at the desired estimate.

To show $(\dagger)$, as you say in the comments you estimate the left-hand side by a double integral, and to bound this one uses the triange inequality to split
$$ \lvert g(x) - g(y) \rvert \leq \lvert g(x) - c \rvert + \lvert c - g(y) \rvert. $$
From here one can integrate out the free variable in the respective terms to conclude. In detail one has
\begin{align}
\int_a^b \left\lvert g(x) - \frac1{b-a} \int_a^b g(y) \,\mathrm{d}y\right\rvert \,\mathrm{d}x 
&\leq \frac1{b-a} \int_a^b \int_a^b \lvert g(x) - g(y) \rvert \,\mathrm{d}y \,\mathrm{d}x\\
&\leq \frac1{b-a}\int_a^b\int_a^b \lvert g(x) - c \rvert + \lvert c - g(y) \rvert \,\mathrm{d}y \,\mathrm{d}x \\
&= \left(\frac1{b-a}\int_a^b\,\mathrm{d} y\right)\int_a^b \lvert g(x) - c \rvert  \,\mathrm{d}x + \left(\frac1{b-a}\int_a^b\,\mathrm{d} x\right)\int_a^b \lvert c - g(y) \rvert  \,\mathrm{d}y \\
&= 2 \int_a^b \lvert g(x) - c \rvert  \,\mathrm{d}x,
\end{align}
as required. Here note that the two integrals in the penultimate line are the same, just that the variable of integration changes from $x$ to $y$.

Comment: I managed to figure it out on my own after looking at the equivalence of the “average oscillation” and “sup inf” definitions of BMO, but thank you for writing up the answer!